# Intersection of identity components

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, classical-groups, centralisers

Let $e_{1}$ and $e_{2}$ be involutions in the algebraic group $G=\operatorname{PGL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. Do we have $$C_{G}(\langle e_{1},e_{2}\rangle)^{\circ} = C_{G}(e_{1})^{\circ}\cap C_{G}(e_{2})^{\circ}.$$ It's obvious $C_{G}(\langle e_{1},e_{2}\rangle)^{\circ} \leqslant C_{G}(e_{1})^{\circ}\cap C_{G}(e_{2})^{\circ}.$ If yes, can it be generalised to two elementary abelian $2$-subgroups $E_{1}, E_{2}$.

Here $H^{\circ}$ denotes the identity component of the group $H$.

I can only see this through some examples. For instance, in $G=\operatorname{PGL}_{4}(\mathbb{C})$, let $$ x=\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1& 0 &  0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &  1
\end{array} \right],f= \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 &  0
\end{array} \right].$$ Then $$C_{G}(x) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
a_{1} & 0 & a_{3} & 0\\
0 & b_{2} & 0 &  b_{4}\\
c_{1} & 0 & c_{3} & 0\\
0 & d_{2} & 0 &  d_{4}
\end{array} \right] \sqcup f\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
a_{1} & 0 & a_{3} & 0\\
0 & b_{2} & 0 &  b_{4}\\
c_{1} & 0 & c_{3} & 0\\
0 & d_{2} & 0 &  d_{4}
\end{array} \right].$$

Let $$ y=\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1& 0 &  0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &  1
\end{array} \right]. \mbox{So } C_{G}(y) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
u_{1} & 0 & u_{3} & u_{4}\\
0 & v_{2} & 0 &  0\\
s_{1} & 0 & s_{3} & s_{4}\\
t_{1} & 0 & t_{3} &  t_{4}
\end{array} \right].$$
So $C_{G}(\langle x,y\rangle)^{\circ} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
* & 0 & * & 0\\
0 & * & 0 &  0\\
* & 0 & * & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &  *
\end{array} \right]\cong A_{1}T_{2}$ which is, indeed, the intersection of the identity components of the two centralisers.

Comment: In your example, $x$ and $y$ lie in a common torus, so everything can be computed in terms of root groups for that torus.  Did you try an example where they do not lie in a common torus?  The first example that occurs to me is two distinct generators of a $V_4$ in $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb C)$, but there the intersection of the connected centralisers comes out to be trivial, so equality does hold.  But that example still has the two involutions commuting, so maybe more interesting things happen if they don't.

Comment: I appreciate your input. Would you please elaborate more on "everything can be computed in terms of root groups for that torus".

Comment: @LSpice Do you mean if we stick to involutions in a common torus, then the conclusion holds? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cent{C}\newcommand\oG{\overline G}\newcommand\oe{\overline e}$Put $\oG = \operatorname{PGL}_n(\mathbb C)$.  I hope you will permit me to denote the involutions by $\oe_i$ instead of $e_i$.

At first, it matters only that we are dealing with semisimple elements (which is implied by being an involution in characteristic $\ne 2$).  It doesn't even matter at first that we are dealing with $\oG = \operatorname{PGL}_n(\mathbb C)$; I will put $G = \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$, but there is a general theory of $z$-extensions, of which every connected, reductive group $\oG$ admits one, which are to $\oG$ as $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ is to $\operatorname{PGL}_n(\mathbb C)$.

If $t$ is any semisimple element of $G$, then $\Cent_G(t)$ is connected, $\Cent_G(t) = \Cent_G(t)^\circ \to \Cent_{\oG}(\overline t)^\circ$ is a surjection, and $\Cent_G(t)$ is the full pre-image in $G$ of $\Cent_{\oG}(\overline t)^\circ$, where $\overline t$ is the image of $t$ in $\oG$.  In particular, if $e_i$ is a lift of $\oe_i$, then $\Cent_{\oG}(\oe_1)^\circ \cap \Cent_{\oG}(\oe_2)^\circ$ is the image in $\oG$ of $\Cent_G(e_1) \cap \Cent_G(e_2) = \Cent_G(e_1, e_2)$.  Thus, the question is whether $\Cent_G(e_1, e_2)$ is connected.  If so, then $\Cent_{\oG}(\oe_1)^\circ \cap \Cent_{\oG}(\oe_2)^\circ$ is the image $\Cent_{\oG}(\oe_1, \oe_2)^\circ$ in $\oG$ of $\Cent_G(e_1, e_2) = \Cent_G(e_1, e_2)^\circ$.

In the full generality that I have considered so far (where $G$ has connected centre and simply connected derived group, and the $e_i$ can be any semisimple elements), this need not be true.  Even in your setting, where $\oG = \operatorname{PGL}_n(\mathbb C)$ and the $\oe_i$ are involutions, I do not know whether $C_G(e_1, e_2)$ is always connected.  However, you have [indicated](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433237/intersection-of-identity-components#comment1115408_433237) that you are interested in the case where $\oe_1$ and $\oe_2$ belong to a common maximal torus $\overline T$ (which is the same as $\oe_2$ belonging to $\Cent_{\oG}(\oe_1)^\circ$).  I now specialise to that case, without requiring that the $\oe_i$ are involutions.  Let $T$ be the pre-image in $G$ of $\overline T$.  Then $T$ is a maximal torus in $G$.

In general (not just for $G = \operatorname{GL}_n$), the map from $\operatorname{stab}_W(e_1, e_2)/\langle s_\alpha : \alpha(e_1) = \alpha(e_2) = 1\rangle$ to $\Cent_G(e_1, e_2)/\Cent_G(e_1, e_2)^\circ$ is an isomorphism, where $W$ is the Weyl group of $T$ in $G$.  Now, finally specialising to $G = \operatorname{GL}_n$ and so identifying $W$ with $\operatorname S_n$, and conjugating $T$ if necessary so that it is the diagonal torus of $G$, an explicit computation shows that $\operatorname{stab}_W(e_1, e_2)$ is the product of permutation groups that respect the decomposition of $\{1, \dotsc, n\}$ into maximal subsets $I$ such that all diagonal entries of $e_1$ with entries in $I$ are equal, and all diagonal entries of $e_2$ with entries in $I$ are equal; and that this is just $\langle s_\alpha : \alpha(e_1) = \alpha(e_2) = 1\rangle$.  Thus, $\Cent_G(e_1, e_2)$ is connected, so your desired conclusion follows.